# Can I tell what udev rule a device is using?

Tags: usb, udev, dmesg, lsusb

I'd like to edit the way a device is created on my Ubuntu 14.10 box.

> Device: USB UART
>   File: /dev/ttyUSB0

Is there any way to find out what udev rule created this? Or do I just write a new one and hope for the best?

**lsusb**

```
user@localhost:~$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
...
user@localhost:~$
```

**dmesg**

```
user@localhost:~$ dmesg
...
[  360.686771] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[  361.149691] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[  361.149696] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  361.149698] usb 2-2.1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[  361.149700] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  361.149702] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: A601EKK6
[  361.199033] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  361.199044] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  361.199051] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  361.229845] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[  361.229860] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[  361.229913] ftdi_sio 2-2.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  361.229935] usb 2-2.1: Detected FT232RL
[  361.229937] usb 2-2.1: Number of endpoints 2
[  361.229939] usb 2-2.1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[  361.229941] usb 2-2.1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[  361.229943] usb 2-2.1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[  361.237661] usb 2-2.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
user@localhost:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way.  read all the rules until you find the ones that match that device.
searchiong for the strings "ttyUSB", "0403" and "6001"  may help.

ttyUSB0 looks like the default device the kernel will create if not overridden by a udev rule.
so I'd wager that no udev rule is yet resonsibkle for that device
.